# What kind of bonds are there between a Transcription Factor and its DNA binding site?

Tags: protein-binding, transcription-factor, binding-sites

I want to know what kind of bonds are there between a Transcription Factor and its DNA binding site when the complex is created. This information will be used to determine the method for a molecular Dynamics simulation, which intends to predict/calculate the binding energy/Gibbs free energy.

Comment: You might take a look at this paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3425445/ ("MM energy functions, on the other hand, are composed of independent, physicochemical energy terms that capture van der Waals and Coulombic interactions, solvation effects, and other atomic interaction energies")

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I would like some more specific information but I found other useful information